# Wifi trouble on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wifi, drivers

I've been tackling this day two now. I recently dual booted Linux Mint on my Windows 10 machine. When I installed it, the wifi driver did not seem to be installed. I can only connect via ethernet cable. I've tried various methods of installing the driver.
`iwconfig`

gives me

```
lo       no wireless extensions.

eth0     no wireless extensions.
```

Whenever I open driver manager, it just updates the cache and downloads packages then displays a blank screen once finished.

`sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer`

does not install anything, and says that b43-fwcutter is already the newest version but alas, still no wifi capabilities.

`lspci -nn | grep 0280 :`

gives me

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3165] (rev 79)
```

I checked the manufacture website and it has my wireless adapter listed as a 802.11ac + Bluetooth 4.0, Dual Band 2.4&5 GHz, 1x1

At some point I kind of just went on a copy & paste frenzy on various forums so I don't really remember what else I tried.

my mind is drawing blanks as to what to try next. Any suggestions?

Comment: See [“Intel Corporation Device 3165” wifi doesn't work](http://askubuntu.com/questions/682658/intel-corporation-device-3165-wifi-doesnt-work) for a solution

Comment: check this answer worked for me when linux mint mate didn't come with wife driver installed http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156216/93717

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was update to the latest kernel 4.2.x since it supported my wireless card.