# (Linux Mint-17) Unable to connect to wireless network

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

I have installed Linux Mint-17 on my laptop.
However, i am unable to connect to any wireless network.
A red dot is flashed under the network icon on the bottom-right corner(near clock).

I referred the link:-
[Connecting Linux Mint to WiFi network](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156212/connecting-linux-mint-to-wifi-network)
which suggested to execute:-

**sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer**

So, i connected by cellphone through USB-tethering and successfully executed this command.
However, the red dot still persists and i am unable to connect to wireless network.

The laptop has a realtek8723BE pci network adapter.

When i execute iwconfig, the output is:-

```
lo       no wireless extensions.

eth0     no wireless extensions.
```

How should i connect to wireless network ??

Comment: Please open terminal and enter `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info`  This is a diagnostic tool and it will create a file named wireless-info.txt.  Please copy the contents of this file and paste at paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL.  Is this a newer HP laptop?

Comment: Nope, this is Lenovo laptop. I will try your solution and get back...

Comment: Meanwhile, i have connected Intex wifi dongle to connect to my Access Point and start internet.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15406059/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install compilation tools:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
```

Next, clone the tree containing the Realtek driver code:

```
 git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723be
```

Finally, compile the code:

```
cd rtl8723be
make clean
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8723be
```

Reboot

Solution 2 : Open the `/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` file in a text editor, with sudo or root permissions. Then, add the following text:

```
 options rtl8723be fwlps=N ips=N
```

Now, for these changes to take effect, reboot.

Comment: `git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723be` results in only a readme file in rtl8723be directory

Answer (score 2):

We can try Larry Fingers driver for the rtl8723be

```
sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms build rtlwifi-new/0.6
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Reboot