# Linux Mint 20.2 : No wireless internet connection option randomly

Tags: linux-mint, wifi

This question is a continuation of [Linux Mint 20.1 : No wireless internet connection option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657100/linux-mint-20-1-no-wireless-internet-connection-option/657186?noredirect=1#comment1238599_657186)

When I boot the PC, sometimes I get the option to connect it to wireless networks but others not (for example, this morning it was connected to WiFi (bad quality connection), but at the evening, no wireless option appears).

I have update from Linux Mint 20.1 to 20.2, the problem happened before and after the update.

I write down some information that might be useful according to the previous question.

System info:

```
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-77-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 5.0.5 
           wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 20.2 Uma base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X571GD_X571GD v: 1.0 
           serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: X571GD v: 1.0 serial: <filter> UEFI: American Megatrends 
           v: X571GD.309 date: 12/17/2020 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 30.1 Wh condition: 30.1/42.3 Wh (71%) volts: 12.7/11.6 
           model: ASUS A32-K55 serial: <filter> status: Full 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-8300H bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Kaby Lake 
           rev: A L2 cache: 8192 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 36799 
           Speed: 4000 MHz min/max: 800/4000 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 4000 2: 3900 3: 4000 
           4: 4000 5: 3998 6: 3904 7: 3989 8: 3884 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           chip ID: 8086:3e9b 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] vendor: ASUSTeK driver: nvidia 
           v: 460.80 bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID: 10de:1c92 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: modesetting,nvidia 
           unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 460.80 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:1f.3 chip ID: 8086:a348 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-77-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 driver: N/A port: 4000 bus ID: 03:00.0 chip ID: 8086:2723 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: ASUSTeK 
           driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 3000 bus ID: 04:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8168 
           IF: enp4s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 1.14 TiB used: 153.06 GiB (13.1%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: SK Hynix model: HFM256GDJTNG-8310A size: 238.47 GiB 
           speed: 15.8 Gb/s lanes: 2 serial: <filter> 
           ID-2: /dev/sda vendor: Toshiba model: MQ04ABF100 size: 931.51 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s 
           serial: <filter> 
RAID:      Hardware-1: Intel 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] driver: ahci v: 3.0 
           bus ID: 00:17.0 chip ID: 8086.282a 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 91.17 GiB used: 29.77 GiB (32.7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 
           ID-2: /home size: 457.35 GiB used: 123.26 GiB (27.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3 
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 14.90 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda2 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 69.0 C mobo: 27.8 C gpu: nvidia temp: 60 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0 
Repos:     No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/megasync.list 
           1: deb https: //mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_20.04/ ./
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list 
           1: deb http: //packages.linuxmint.com uma main upstream import backport #id:linuxmint_main
           2: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
           3: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
           4: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
           5: deb http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
           6: deb http: //archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ focal partner
Info:      Processes: 257 Uptime: 9m Memory: 15.49 GiB used: 2.04 GiB (13.2%) Init: systemd v: 245 
           runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 alt: 9 Client: Unknown python3.8 client inxi: 3.0.38
```

Output of `lspci -nn | grep 0280`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
```

Output of `iwconfig`:

```
enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I already tried to update the system via update and upgrade.

EDIT 1:
According to @Artem S. Tashkinov

Output of `sudo dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn`

```
MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
 #5 #6 #7
ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_TZ.ETMD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.GPLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.TPLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.GUPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.TUPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS05._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS05._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS07._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS07._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS08._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS08._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS09._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS09._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS10._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS11._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS11._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS12._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS12._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS13._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS13._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS14._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS14._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR1._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR1._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR2._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR2._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS01._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS01._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS02._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS02._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS03._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS03._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS04._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS04._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS05._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS05._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS06._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS06._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS07._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS07._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS08._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS08._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS09._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS09._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS10._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS10._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
ACPI: Invalid active0 threshold
[Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)
usb: port power management may be unreliable
i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
acpi PNP0C14:03: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:02)
acpi PNP0C14:04: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:02)
r8169 0000:04:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
i2c_hid i2c-ELAN1200:00: i2c-ELAN1200:00 supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
i2c_hid i2c-ELAN1200:00: i2c-ELAN1200:00 supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator
iwlwifi: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -110
nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  460.80  Fri May  7 06:55:54 UTC 2021
kauditd_printk_skb: 12 callbacks suppressed
ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20190816/nsarguments-59)
mce: CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU7: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 1)
mce: CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5)
mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5)
mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5)
mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5)
mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5)
mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5)
mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5)
mce: CPU7: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5)
mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5)
mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 5)
mce: CPU3: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 28)
mce: CPU7: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 28)
mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 28)
mce: CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 28)
mce: CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 28)
mce: CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 28)
mce: CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 28)
mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 28)
mce: CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 28)
mce: CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 28)
```

Output of `sudo dmesg -t | grep -i firm`

```
Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)
[drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-20-1-3.sfi
Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 2161510 usecs
```

Output of `sudo rfkill`

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE              SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      asus-wlan      unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth asus-bluetooth   blocked unblocked
 2 bluetooth hci0             blocked unblocked
```

Comment: I don't like these messages in your log **Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled**. It's quite possible your WiFi adapter refuses to work because it overheats. Please start with checking that the fans actually work, blowing dust out of your laptop and updating its BIOS just in case. Lastly I'd try increasing the singal strength on your WiFi router. Some routers are not configured by default to their maximum values. It could be something else entirely. Wi-Fi is a finicky thing.

Comment: It is true that my PC is hot, and it makes sense now that at the morning, when the ambient temperature was cold everything worked, and now at the afternoon, not. Moreover I also have Windows 10 installed and I don't have WiFi problems, I don't hnow if the temperature controll depends on the OS. Note: fans work, I also will try to clean dust (if I can open the laptop)

Comment: Please try updating BIOS first. Overheating problems could be easily fixed by it.

Comment: I finally decided to move to Windows 10 completelly due to slow system, mechanical sounds (not due to fans) when executing some programs, overheating laptop (and an acquaintance said me that updating the BIOS might be dangerous or very sensible to errors). When I bought the laptop, two years ago, it was impossible to install Linux Mint or Ubuntu, I didn't know why, but I think is was due to graphic card incompatibility, idk. So I think drivers or OS are not doing a good performance.