# Linux Mint 18 can't connect to any wifi network

Tags: networking, linux-mint, wifi, troubleshooting

I have recent issues with WIFI not working on my fresh Mint installation.
When trying to connect to my home WIFI it asks me again for password after 2sec and then again after 5sec to finally drop connection.
After multiple tries I've managed to connect to the internet for like 1-2 sec and instantly getting disconnected but that happened only once. I can't connect to local hotspot either, which I can easily do on my smartphone/Windows. Can't test cable connection for now, but it wasn't working on Elementary OS.

I'm using full installation on USB pendrive, it's working perfectly on Windows or another laptop, just having issue with this one.
I had the same issue on Ubuntu and Elementary OS recently, all fine but Wifi. Tried also to connect with Ethernet cable on Elementary OS, yet no internet.

My spec:
Gigabyte MOBO (it normally requires drivers for Windows to enable network card). Updated BIOS.
Some 1 year old Realtek PCI adapter. I've updated official drivers from their website.
Mint 18 on USB Pendrive in persistence mode.

Some logs:
http://pastebin.com/Za6T4fkS
http://pastebin.com/kyphxntx

Connection is not soft/hard blocked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this answer worked for me when linux mint mate didn't come with wife driver installed http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156216/93717