# How to get Broadcom drivers working in Linux Mint 19.3 without network access?

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, xfce, broadcom

I'd like to install Linux Mint (Xfce) with Broadcom support, when I don't have network access after a fresh Mint install. I've already read [the answers here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156212/connecting-linux-mint-to-wifi-network), which all require network access of some kind.

Here's the scenario: I boot into the live image, and when I go into Driver Manager, I can enable Broadcom support and get WiFi access during the live session.

However, when I boot into the fresh install, trying the same thing doesn't work, because the driver manager asks for a network connection OR the Mint installation media (which must have the drivers; otherwise, how did I get WiFi access during the live session?). I must be encountering a bug, because mounting the installation media and clicking OK doesn't do anything, even though it's clearly intended to solve this issue.

How can I diagnose what's preventing the drivers from loading?

I'm not sure if this helps, but with Mx Linux, I was able to get WiFi working during the live session (same idea—loading Broadcom drivers), and when I booted into the fresh install, the drivers were already there (didn't have to change them again).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
dmesg | grep 14e4
```

or

```
lspci -nn -d 14e4:
```

These will at least tell you that the driver exists in your system,
and makes things simple. 
If not, please provide the above output in your question.

Both should return with something like this...

```
0.296619] pci 0000:02:00.0: [14e4:4365] type 00 class 0x028000
```

(Note `14e4` is Broadcom Providers signature for all their devices.)

In my case `4365` is the product id, as you indicate you've tried the suggestions (as did I) in your OP. My suggestion is to install `brcmwl-kernel-source`.

Why? If your case is the same as mine,
your model cannot be solved by `b43-cutter`, nor by the `broadcomm-sta` code. 
By installing and building the source above,
you should get the correct module `wl` , seen as `brcml-0` in `rfkill list`.

A better guide to the process (so I do not repeat others' work) is found at
[Install Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) . Look up your device and follow the correct guide for your card/device.

As a side note, I found the whole process cumbersome (mint 17[no driver] to 19[keeps my brcm-kernel-source install]).

I connect to my mobile Wi-Fi using `wpa_supplicant`.
(after installing brcwl..
The following steps:

0. setup interface file for wlan0, netmask, gateww
1. `iwlist wlan0 s`
   (first time doesn't work)
2. `ifconfig wlan0 up`
3. `wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -cyour_wifi_wpa_supplicant.conf`
4. `dhclient wlan0`

It does work!
Update: wlan0 is no longer valid and has been superseded by wlp{x}s{n} ; where x = pci bus number and n = slot, e.g. wlp2s0.

[With the introduction of systemd,more info can be found here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/702161/why-is-my-interface-now-wlp2s0-instead-of-wlan0)

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I can't mark it as correct because I can't test it at the moment (already done with my installation). I think I used a different procedure that was a bit simpler though. I'll try to dig it up, if you want to add it to your answer as well.

Comment: I used the answer in the last post here: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=250094, **which involved browsing the live usb after installation (from your actual OS) and going to: "/pool/main/b/bcmwl and double clicked to install bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu1~1.1_amd64.deb"**

In my case, it also asked for **libc6-dev** and another dependency which I don't remember. So, I worked my way back, searching the usb for those files and using gdebi to install them. But that was it, double clicking those three files in the order that Mint asked for.